# Checking If Cons exist in list of Cons

Tags: lisp

I am building a program and lisp and need to check if a Cons exist in a list of cons, but for some reason it keep returning nil in the if statement, here is the current code I am using for it.

```
(defun countVertexTriangles (graph numOfVertices)
    (findTriangle graph numOfVertices)
)

(defun findTriangle(graph numOfVertices)
    (loop for (x y) in graph do
            (loop for z from 1 to numOfVertices do
                (write graph)
                (terpri)
                (write (cons z (cons y nil)))
                (terpri)
                (write (cons z (cons x nil)))
                (terpri)
                ; (if (AND (member (cons z (cons y nil)) graph) (member (cons z (cons x nil)) graph))
                ;     then (write (cons y z))
                ; )
            )
        (terpri)
    )
)

; (defun findEdge(graph edge)
;     (loop for x in graph do
;         (write x)
;         (write edge)
;         (if (eql x edge)
;             (write "A")
;             (write "B")
;         )
;     )
; )

(defun testFunct ()
    (setf g1 '((1 2)(2 3)(1 3)(2 4)(3 4)(4 5)(3 5)))
    (countVertexTriangles g1 5)
)

(testFunct)
```

Why does the member(cons z (cons y nil)) return nil even when in the first iteration we can see (1 2) exists in the list?

Edit:

Currently even when it is true it returns nil, why would this be the case given the following code?

```
(defun countVertexTriangles (graph numOfVertices)
    (findTriangle graph numOfVertices)
)

(defun findTriangle(graph numOfVertices)
    (loop for (x y) in graph do
            (loop for z from 1 to numOfVertices do
                ; (write graph)
                ; (terpri)
                ; (write (list z y ))
                ; (terpri)
                (write (findEdge graph (list z y)))
                (terpri)
                ; (if (AND (member (list z x) graph) (member (list z x ) graph))
                ;     then (write "TEST")
                ; )
            )
        (terpri)
    )
)

(defun findEdge(graph edge)
    (loop for x in graph do
        (if (equal x edge)
            (return-true)
            (return-false)
        )
    )
)

(defun return-true ()
   t)

(defun return-false ()
   nil)

(defun testFunct ()
    (setf g1 '((1 2)(2 3)(1 3)(2 4)(3 4)(4 5)(3 5)))
    (countVertexTriangles g1 5)
)
```

Comment: You're creating new conses by calling `cons`, they can't possibly be `eql` to the conses in the list. Use `equal`

Comment: You don't use `then` when using the `if` macro.

Comment: The only code with `if` in it is commented out. Show the code with the problem, not the code that doesn't have an error.

Comment: FYI, `(cons x (cons y nil))` is usually written as `(list x y)`

Comment: @Barmar Both corrections to changing eql to equal and to (list x y) fixed it!

Comment: @Barmar Currently when i print findEdge it always return nil even when I can see it hits the return-true function, why is my findEdge function not returning true?

Comment: You're not returning anything from `findEdge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findEdge` doesn't return anything. Calling `return-true` and `return-false` doesn't return from `findEdge`. You also shouldn't return until you find a match.

```
(defun findEdge(graph edge)
    (loop for x in graph do
        (if (equal x edge)
            (return-from findEdge (return-true))
        )
    )
    (return-false)
)
```

This can be simplified to just:

```
(defun findEdge (graph edge) 
  (member edge findEdge :test #'equal))
```